# Graph Theory: function for a DAG?

Tags: directed-acyclic-graphs

For a directed acyclic graph where vertices have numerical labels what is the best way to return the maximum label on a vertex reachable from vertex u (including u itself)? Ideally it should run in time linear in the size of the graph.

Comment: I think that a simple recursive function should do the trick. Remember: a DAG is just a n-ary tree, so the set of vertices reachables from `u` form a sub-tree.

Comment: +1 to rodrigo. Further, remember that the linearity is: `O(|E|+|V|)`